# Reference member being modified in arraylist.forEach?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a survival simulator, and I have a `arrayList` of `Entity`s. I am writing a `checkForDead()` method which will delete the member if it is dead. Right now, I have a long `for` statement to do this. However, I would like to use `arrayList.forEach()` in order to make it more readable. As mentioned, part of the action will have to be deleting it. How do I reference the memeber being modified in the `forEach()` method? For example

```
a.forEach(a.remove(x));
```

Where `a` is the list and `x` is the member being modified. How can I get what `x` is?

Original code in the `checkForDead` method:

```
for (int x = 0; x < a.size(); x++) {

            if (a.get(x).calories <= 0) {
                Fates.addDeathRecord(a.get(x).name, x, "starved to death");
                a.remove(x);
            }

            else if (a.get(x).hydration <= 0) {
                Fates.addDeathRecord(a.get(x).name, x, "died of thirst");
                a.remove(x);
            }

            else if (a.get(x).heat <= 0) {
                Fates.addDeathRecord(a.get(x).name, x, "froze to death");
                a.remove(x);
            }

            else if (a.get(x).heat >= 14) {
                Fates.addDeathRecord(a.get(x).name, x, "overheated");
                a.remove(x);
            }

            else if (a.get(x).moral <= Chance.randomNumber(0, 2)) {
                Fates.addDeathRecord(a.get(x).name, x, "commited suicide");
                a.remove(x);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can we see your original code? Did you use enhanced-for-loop `for (element : list)` or simple one `for (int i=0...)`?

Comment: You are currently skipping an entry for evaluation after you remove an entry. Because you still increment to look at the next index, even though you removed the current index, causing all later entries to shift.

Comment: Nice catch. I will try to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method may not be appropriate for structurally modifying the collection being iterated over. As noted in the javadoc:

> The default implementation behaves as if:
>
> ```
>  for (T t : this)
>      action.accept(t);
> ```

Depending on the `List` implementation you are using, manipulating the collection by adding or removing can cause a ConcurrentModificationException. This is a case where using the traditional `Iterator` and [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) is likely still the best solution.

```
//keep track of index for death record
int x = 0;
for (Iterator<Entry> iter = a.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ++x) {

        final Entry next = iter.next();
        if (next.calories <= 0) {
            Fates.addDeathRecord(next.name, x, "starved to death");
            iter.remove();
        }

        else if (next.hydration <= 0) {
            Fates.addDeathRecord(next.name, x, "died of thirst");
            iter.remove();
        }

        else if (next.heat <= 0) {
            Fates.addDeathRecord(next.name, x, "froze to death");
            iter.remove();
        }

        else if (next.heat >= 14) {
            Fates.addDeathRecord(next.name, x, "overheated");
            iter.remove();
        }

        else if (next.moral <= Chance.randomNumber(0, 2)) {
            Fates.addDeathRecord(next.name, x, "commited suicide");
            iter.remove();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use a lambda expression like the following.

```
a.foreach(element -> {
    // access element
    System.out.println(element.name);
    // do other stuff
});
```

You may want to check out the [removeIf()-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), it removes all elements that fulfill a given condition.

Comment: Using `removeIf` provides a simular problem - how could I access the data in the object?

Comment: `a.removeIf(e -> {e.name...`   One of the problems with using a lambda for this is it appears you need the index of the entry for the death record. That is not trivial to keep track of with a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Entity> toRemove = new ArrayList<Entitys>();
for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
    if (a.get(i).checkForDead()){
         toRemove.add(a.get(i));
         a.remove(i);
}
for (int i=0; i<toRemove.size(); i++){
    ..your code..
}
```

Comment: No, removing elements from the end would kill an entity that is not dead.

Comment: Each entity has it's own stats. Simply removing the last one would be against the point of the simulator, as it would leave a dead man alive and a live man dead.

Comment: You can delete from an iterator, but not directly on a list. But it is best to just throw away the input and not modify it.